# how to make visible list in sencha touch2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i am new to sencha touch2. i want display list in a page. binding is happening successful. but i am not able to see data but able to scroll page. please any one can help me. i facing this issue. thank you.

My code is here:

```
Ext.define("Sencha.view.ProjectListView", {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',    
    xtype: 'projectListepage',
    id: 'projectListepage',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.JsonP'
    ],
    config: {
        scrollable: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'JSONP'
        },
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                flex: 3,
                items: [{
                    text: 'Project Deatils',
                    handler: function () {
                        var list = Ext.getCmp('JSONP'),
                        tpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
                            '<tpl for=".">',
                                   '<img src="{MainImageUrl}"/><label>{ProjectName}</label><p class="temp_low">{ShortDescription}</p>', //                                                                    
                            '</tpl>',
                    ]);
                        Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                            url: 'http://localhost:53985/PropertyService.svc/GetAllProject',
                            callbackKey: 'callback',
                            params: {

                            },
                            callback: function (success, request) {
                                var project = request;
                                if (project) {
                                    list.updateHtml(tpl.applyTemplate(project));
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert('There was an error retrieving the weather.');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }]
            }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anywhere in your code sample where you are creating a list. You need to extend `'Ext.List'` or use `xtype:'list'`. There are a few simple examples in the sencha touch 2 docs on how to create a list.  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List